# What does a static library that depends on another static library contain?

Tags: c++, macos

I have 3 projects:

`Utils`, which is compiled to `Utils.a`

`ExtraUtils` which is compiled to `ExtraUtils.a` and is linked against Utils.a
and `Main`, which is compiled to `Main.exe` and needs both `Utils.a` and `ExtraUtils.a` in order to function.

Does `ExtraUtils.a` contain `Utils.a` ? Does it contain a reference to `Utils.a`? Do I need to have both linked when compiling `Main`?

Comment: I'd guess you need both libraries. What does your linker actually say?

Comment: What do you mean: "ExtraUtils.a is linked against Utils.a"? When you create a `.a`, you are basically creating a zip (well, other format) of a bunch of `.o`, no linking involved.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ op's linker seems to say *needs both Utils.a and ExtraUtils.a in order to function* which kinda answers most of the question already..

Comment: A static library is just a bunch of object files one after the other . It's not linked at all. (unless you specify partial linking, which is different)

Comment: If Utils and ExtraUtils were totally unrelated you would not have asked the question. Therefore, I think ExtraUtils is dependent upon Utils? You could state that to make the question clearer. You will always need to link Utils when building an app using ExtraUtils.

Comment: It depends on the operating system. C++ standard does not talk about libraries. I guess you are talking about linux, but please specify which operating system/compiler are you talking about

Comment: @pqnet It's osx, I'll edit the tags.

Comment: @user2672165 I said that extrautils.a is linked against utils.a so they're related.

Comment: I think linked is not the correct word to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, a `.a` file is nothing but a collection of object files (`.o`) combined into a single file. It also contains some data structures that allow the compiler to more easily find the object files it needs, but that's strictly speaking an optimization.

When you link to an `.a` the linker looks for each unsatisfied symbol which, if any, object file in that library defines that symbol, and if it finds such an object, it includes that object file in the executable.

Now creation of an `.a` file does *not* involve linking. It just involves specification of the object files which should be put into the library.

Now when you create `ExtraUtils.a` you *could* specify that `ExtraUtils.a` shall also contain all objects of `Utils.a`. Then linking with `ExtraUtils.a` would not require linking with `Utils.a`. But normally you'll specify that it shall contain only the extra files, since the original files are already in `Utils.a`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you create those .a archive.

In normal situation you create the Utils.a with just the objects for Utils, and create ExtraUtils.a with just the extra file, but you may also merge the .a files as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

> Does ExtraUtils.a contain Utils.a

Not unless you built it that way.

> Does it contain a reference to Utils.a?

Yes.

> Do I need to have both linked when compiling Main?

Yes.

Comment: "reference to Utils.a": No. It has references to symbols that happen to be defined in Utils.a, but you won't find the string "Utils.a" anywhere in ExtraUtils.a (well, except possibly as part of the string "ExtraUtils.a" obviously).